# Censoring an input text file and writing it to an output text file

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that inputs a list of words and a list of banned words. It will then "censor" the original list of words by changing any banned word in that file to asterisks. Finally, it will write the censored list of words into an output file. This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment_5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try{
  ArrayList<String> bWords = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream ("banned.txt"));
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter ("output.txt");
  while(sc.hasNext()){
    bWords.add(sc.next());
  }
  sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
  while (sc.hasNext())
    words.add(sc.next());

  String replacement = "test";
  for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < bWords.size(); j++){
      if (words.get(i).compareTo(bWords.get(j)) == 0){
        for (int k = 0; k < words.get(i).length(); k++)
          replacement = "*";
        words.set(i, replacement);
        replacement = ""; 
      } 
    }

    for(i=0; i< words.size(); i++){
         pw.println(words.get(i));
        }
        pw.close();
     }
   }
   catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.toString());
   }
```

It compiles fine and it creates an "output.txt" file, but the file is blank. I can't seem to figure out why it won't work. Any help would be great

UDPATE: It now prints out because I added a for loop in front of the PrintWriter (updated in code), but now it's only printing out the input, and not the censored input

Comment: Note that writing and reading to/from files should be done with **NIO** (Javas new I/O API). It revolves around the classes `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`. And if you're not using it, at least probably close your resources using `sc.close()` and `pw.close()`, or use **try-with-resources**.

Comment: Try to **encapsulate the problem**. First check if you're even writing something to your file. Add `System.out.println("Writing: " + words.get(i));` next to your `pw` variable and see if it even outputs something. If not, check if you added something to your `words` collection (again using some small print statements).

Comment: I could also imagine that your `replacement = ""; ` somehow replaced **all words** by `""` due to some errors in your logic. Try setting it to `replacement = "test";` and see if the file now contains lots of `test`. The same holds for the initialization `String replacement = "";`, replace it temporarily by `test` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter ("output.txt");
```

this line in code is rewriting the file again and again.
what you can do is put this out of loop.
Also don't forget to close the stream after end of loop.

```
pw.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure? I mean that definitely holds for some of the streams (like `FileOutputStream`) but `PrintWriter` doesn't even have such a constructor. It has a constructor accepting an `OutputStream` and a `boolean` but that boolean only means **auto-flush** (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-)).

Comment: yeah.. let me check the correct way.. but the problem seems here only.

Comment: You could invoke it as `new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true))` but I *think* the default behavior of `PrintWriter` (if invoked on a `String`) is to **append**.